# Findstr second column and make new batch

Tags: batch-file

As you can see, the batch file makes a VBS script and it should make another batch file, but it doesn't, since `findstr /R "^ECHO" "%~sf0" >> "temp.bat"`
copies the code including the `echo`. I want to copy the line after `ECHO` and place them in a temporary file.

Here is my code

```
@echo off
echo This is batch

:::wscript.echo "This VBScript"
:::wscript.echo "Today is " & day(date) & "-" & month(date) & "-" & year(date)
findstr "^:::" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs

goto b

ECHO @echo off
ECHO setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
ECHO set SCRIPT_INSTANCES=20
ECHO :: Create a temporary file if one doesn't already exist
ECHO if not exist script_count.txt >script_count.txt echo(%SCRIPT_INSTANCES%
ECHO :: Read in the value of the config file
ECHO set /p script_counter=<script_count.txt
ECHO :: If the value of script_counter is greater than 1, decrement it and start again
ECHO if %script_counter% gtr 1 (
ECHO     set /a script_counter-=1
ECHO     >script_count.txt echo(!script_counter!
ECHO 
ECHO     start "" cmd /c "%~0"
ECHO ) else (
ECHO     del script_count.txt
ECHO )
ECHO color a 
ECHO :a
ECHO tree C:/
ECHO goto a)

:b
findstr  /R "^ECHO" "%~sf0" >> "temp.bat"
pause
exit
```

Comment: @Squashman if possible make complete edits. Don't just fix just a mistake. Another editor will come and will fix another mistake, etc. and as a result there will be a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip off the leading echo by using the space as a delimiter.

So change this line.

```
findstr  /R "^ECHO" "%~sf0" >> "temp.bat"
```

To this

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%G IN ('findstr  /R "^ECHO" "%~sf0"') DO echo %%H >>"temp.bat"
```

One drawback to this code is that it will strip all the indentation of your code.

Comment: I just used it but it did not work :( any sugestions.

Comment: the batch file opens but noting comes out even a pause after wont stop the script it just exits and nothing happends

Comment: At first I'd change the search string to `^ECHO\>`. Then I'd use `echo(%%H` here in order to avoid `ECHO is off.` messages in the output. `DELIMS= ` is actually not necessary as it defaults to space and tab anyway (but that's a matter of taste, I guess). Finally, I'd put the whole `for /F` loop in between parantheses and redirect all at once by `> "temp.bat"`...

Comment: thx for the help works now but i dont really know what all the parameters do now . wich i did but this looks next level can someone explain what it means to the computer

Comment: @Pietercrafter, if you read  the help file for the `FOR` command you will see that it can do a couple of different things.  One of them is the ability to capture the output of another command. When you capture the output of that command you have a few options to manipulate that data.  In this instance we are separating each line into two tokens (variables). The first variable gets assigned everything before the delimiter. The second variable gets assigned everything after the delimiter.